# How can i get that system command's return to variable?

Tags: perl, return, system

I have a sample code like this :

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
my $path = shift;
my $max_number_of_files = shift;
print("Changing directory to path $path $!" . "\n");
chdir($path) or die "Cant chdir to $path $!";
print("Counting files..." . "\n");
counting();
sub counting {
$counted = system("ls -1 | wc -l");
if ($counted > $max_number_of_files) {
print("You have more or equal files");
return 1;
}
else {
    print("$counted");
    print "You have less files";
    return 2;
}
}
```

But my value $counted i think not get the value which system command show to console. I checked it and it is always zero. How can i handle this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `system` is the exit code of the process that you called by `system`, not the output of the process.

To get the process output, use:

```
chomp($counted = `ls -1 | wc -l`);
```

Comment: Can't modify scalar chomp in scalar assignment at Counter.pl line 9, near "`ls -1 | wc -l`;"
it gives an error like this. What does chomp do ?

Comment: @Hayra Oops, the position of parentheses was not correct, fixed now. FYI, `chomp` gets rid of the new line symbol at the end of a string.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally considered bad practice to parse the output of `ls` because filenames can contain newlines which make them span more than one line and and `wc` will count them more than once.

You could try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files=<*>;
print scalar(@files)," files\n";
```

Also, in terms of portability, you will do better using Perl's built-in features, since `ls` and `wc` may not be available on some (e.g. Windows) machines.